# Huawei Y210d Firmware Flashing Failed

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware

I have an *Huawei Ascend y210d* on which I installed CWM recovery. After that I installed a custom ROM, but now I want to flash its official firmware.

But its official firmware is not installing. It got told using Huawei firmware Indian version [downloaded from Huawei](http://www.huaweidevice.co.in/Downloads/HUAWEI_Y210-Android-2_3_V100R001C151B854SP01_India.rar). I am using this procedure:

- first copy dload (in dload folder `update.app` file is present) folder to the root of the SDcard
- then turn off your device pick out battery then again insert battery
- then press buttons <kbd>volumeup</kbd>+<kbd>volumedown</kbd>+<kbd>powerbutton</kbd>
- then its start unpacking the update package But in step 2 it failed on installing.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

This is the error.log I get in SD Card :

```
{filename = /mmc1/dload/update.app 
call RCV_MODULE_END_EVENT failed,module = OEMSBL_VER_LIST
CMD=0xf,moduleaddr = 0xf0000000, len_tmp=0x2c54
filename = /mmc1/dload/update.app}
```

What can I do to get this fixed?

Comment: Yes my device is rooted and i have installed an Custom ROM also and update.app file is for my device i have downloaded from official website.

Comment: in clockwork recovery i have formatted system and other i have fully formatted device nothing is there and then again i have tried but it failed on installing                  please help

Comment: As I wrote before in a comment (which I've now removed to keep things clean – and ask you to do the same for yours, except for the last comment): if it is an update, as the [listing on the download-page](http://www.huaweidevice.co.in/Support/Downloads/) says, it might/will fail if it cannot detect a "valid" previous (stock) version installed on the device. The file size also indicates it only contains updated components, not a full firmware. You will need a *full* install. Not being familiar with Huawei devices, I have to leave detailed help to someone else.

Comment: OK so please give me the firmware of huawei y210d

Comment: @Rohitraj See [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Comment: any body is not here to help me

Comment: please help me please

Comment: You have not provided all the information. Firstly, what was the version you had before trying to upload from Indian site? Last  4 digits indicate the version. Version compatibility is a major issue with Huawei (I own honor 6). Next did you flash stock recovery before trying to update. If not major cause for failure.

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions, flash each `UPDATE.APP` in order:

1. Transfer > put the `UPDATE.APP` file in a new folder `sdcard\dload` and run forced upgrade (vol up + down)
2. dload (main) > overwrite `UPDATE.APP` in `sdcard\dload`, run forced upgrade again
3. vendor > overwrite `UPDATE.APP` in `sdcard\dload` and run forced upgrade for the last time

Note:

- the `UPDATE.APP` needs to be copied from each folder to `sdcard\dload\`
- phone should reboot after each forced upgrade

Answer (score -1):

Install Any Recovery Like CRM or TWRP....

search for "Room original del huawei y210D" in youtube. Exactly as given.... u will see one HD video link in search result.. downlaod the file mentioned in description of the vdo...
Download the rom file mentioned in youtube vdo description

Wipe the OS of ur mobile. wipe cache.. and others. Keep downloaded zip file in SD card.
Install using recovery....
Enjoy....

Comment: Search for a Youtube video to read its description, to find a link to the real ROM? That doesn't sound like a trustworthy way to find software that can completely take over your phone. If you can update your answer to link directly to a trustworthy source, please do.